# How do I configure vscode live server to process php files properly (it is work very well with .html files )?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, live

I am trying to develop web pages with php calls using vscode and vscode live server. I have installed live server and it works fine with html/css/js. However if the code I'm developing refers to a .php file, I just get the text of the php file, it is not executed by the server. I did find live-server-web-extensions which installs into the chrome browser, presumably to do a reload when the php files are modified as well.

So what I need to know is: How do I configure the server to process php files? I do have php.exe on my system, and if I used the php browser, things work fine. But I'd like to use vscode and live server for development, and I'm missing the secret sauce. I'm am using the Chrome browser and Windows 10[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlxBE.png)

Comment: @RufusVS  can solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your question seems to target server configuration, so I would recommend to ask it on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @MaxMuster Server Fault does not handle developer environments.